# Documentation Example deletion does not appear correctly in side-by-side review

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-review

When reviewing an edit where an entire example is deleted, the side-by-side view still shows the deleted text on the right-hand side. Ideally it ought to be blank -- right now folks are getting confused into thinking there's no change.

Check out [this proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/99912) as an example. The removed section is correctly highlighted in red in all view modes, but when going to either side-by-side mode, the left- and right-hand sides are identical.

I'd pull in more examples if there were some in the review queue, but alas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side by side diffs now show that a deletion is happening.  Inline displays remain the same.

[image: gif]

Comment: All better now. Much obliged!